# Webpack resolve-url-loader resolving incorrect paths

Tags: npm, webpack, sass, resolveurl

I'm making use of the `resolve-url-loader` which is working great for importing third party stylesheets that are in turn linking to their own assets.

However, i'm struggling to understand how in the instance below my reference to `owl.jpg` from `app.scss` manages to successfully resolve?

**Folder structure:**

```
src/
|
|- index.html
|
|-img/
|  owl.jpg
|
|- scss/
|   app.scss
|   
|-js/
|  app.js
```

**app.scss**

These incorrect paths to the asset still seem to resolve?

```
.owl {
    background: url('owl.jpg');
}

.owl {
    background: url('/owl.jpg');
}

.owl {
    background: url('img/owl.jpg');
}
```

Surely the path should only resolve with the below path?

```
.owl {
    background: url('../img/owl.jpg');
}
```

Am i missing something? Is the resolve-url-loader clever enough to resolve incorrect paths??

Answer (score -1):

You have to compile your scss file to css, browser works only with `.css` files. Then choose the output folder, i guess it can be `src/css`, and then enter a correct path in your css depending on images folder.

If webpack compiles scss files without errors, it just could be incorrect url to image. If correct, `background-size` property should be added with `100% 100%` parameters.

```
.owl {
  background-image: (path/to/image.img);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: He can use webpack loaders for that (and he probably does), `gulp-sass` isn't the only option to compile `sass` files.

Comment: Yes I am compiling my SCSS to CSS. What I don't understand is how the incorrect paths I've listed above manage to successfully resolve.

Comment: @Samuel did you find an answer for this matter, i'm facing the same problem.